# How to edit PdfTemplate width (in Java)

Tags: itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to edit width of PdfTemplate object before close of document ?
In my pdf process I create a document, and set a template for write total page number. I set width but it doesnot works :

```
// onOpenDocument
PdfTemplate pageNumTemplate = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(10, 20);
globalDataMap.put("myTemplate", pageNumTemplate)

// onCloseDocument
Font font = (Font) globalDataMap.get("myFont");
String pagenum = String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber());

float widthPoint = font.getBaseFont().getWidthPoint(pagenum, font.getSize());
PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = (PdfTemplate) globalDataMap.get("myTemplate");
pdfTemplate.setWidth(widthPoint);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfTemplate, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(pagenum), 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Considering your non-capitalization of method names you seem to use iText/Java, not iTextSharp/.Net. Correct?

Comment: Furthermore *it doesnot works* is not a very exact issue description. Do you mean the code makes the program exit unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An error in the OP's initial code

You call `ColumnText.showTextAligned` with a `String` as third parameter:

```
String pagenum = String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber());
[...]
ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfTemplate, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, pagenum, 0, 1, 0);
```

But all `ColumnText.showTextAligned` overloads expect a `Phrase` there:

```
public static void showTextAligned(final PdfContentByte canvas, final int alignment, final Phrase phrase, final float x, final float y, final float rotation)

public static void showTextAligned(final PdfContentByte canvas, int alignment, final Phrase phrase, final float x, final float y, final float rotation, final int runDirection, final int arabicOptions)
```

(at least up to the current 5.5.9-SNAPSHOT development version).

Thus, you might want to use

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfTemplate, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(pagenum), 0, 1, 0);
```

instead.

### But now it works

Based on the OP's code I built this proof-of-concept:

```
try (   FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "dynamicTemplateWidths.pdf"))    )
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A6);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, stream);
    writer.setPageEvent(new PdfPageEventHelper()
    {
        PdfTemplate dynamicTemplate = null;
        Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(), 12);
        String postfix = "0123456789";

        @Override
        public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            super.onOpenDocument(writer, document);
            dynamicTemplate = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(10, 20);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            writer.getDirectContent().addTemplate(dynamicTemplate, 100, 300);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            float widthPoint = font.getBaseFont().getWidthPoint(postfix, font.getSize());
            dynamicTemplate.setWidth(widthPoint / 2.0f);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(dynamicTemplate, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber()) + "-" + postfix), 0, 1, 0);
        }

    });
    document.open();

    document.add(new Paragraph("PAGE 1"));
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("PAGE 2"));

    document.close();
}
```

The output:

[image: dynamicTemplateWidths.pdf]

Considering I set the template width to half the width of the postfix `0123456789` in `onCloseDocument`, this is exactly as expected.